# command failed: Failed to run a backup using the available strategies. neo4j-admin backup command

Tags: database, neo4j, backup

```
neo4j-admin backup --from=IP:PortNum --backup-dir=/home/ubuntu/neo4jdevdump --name=neodbdump --fallback-to-full=true --check-consistency=true --pagecache=4G
```

I am running above command to take backup of neo4j DB but facing error command failed: Failed to run a backup using the available strategies.
I am using `neo4j-admin backup` rather than `neo4j-backup`, because `neo4j-backup` is deprecated.

Comment: What is your Neo4j version ?

Comment: solved the issue. I given IP as 127.0.0.1:6362-6372 which is given in there release document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved the issue.
I gave IP as 127.0.0.1:6362-6372 in `--from` tag, which is given in official document of Neo4j.